# How do i pass a initial value from within a form to a new form?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

If i try to add a new object within a django form how can i pass a initial value to this new form?
I know how to set an initial value on form init but i dont know how to do it form within a new form
any help?`enter code here`

```
Model A
X = CharField()
Y = ForeignKey(ModelB)


Model B
Z = CharField()
```

After setting X a value im saving the model.
Im able to add a new objects Y within the ModelA form, this will **open** a new form of ModelB. How do i pass the value of X to this new form i just opened?
I need X to make a filter a query on Z and i cant find a solution to this

EDIT:

```
class PrecoPorEpocaForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Preco_por_epoca
            fields = ('epoca',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PrecoPorEpocaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

           #if kwargs['initial']['epoca_hotel']:
             #   print kwargs['initial']['epoca_hotel']
            #    self.fields['epoca'].queryset = Epoca.objects.filter(hotel=s)
            #print "TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT"




class TabelaPrecoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TabelaPrecos
        fields = ('client', 'year','hotel', 'seasonprice', 'teste')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(TabelaPrecoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.hotel != None:
             self.fields['seasonprice'].queryset = Preco_por_epoca.objects.filter(epoca__hotel = self.instance.hotel)
```

Comment: Basically you would need to pass some sort of object id through the request for the new form. However, you need to provide more detail so that we can help....

Comment: Thats why im stuck until now, i dont know how to pass the instance id to the new form

Comment: Can you show your views.py? It would be interesting how you exit your first form.

Comment: Just edited the question to better explain the situation, Im working with Django-Admin view

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting corrrectly what you want to do, you need to turn around the relation:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    X = CharField()

class Model B(models.Model):
    Z = CharField()
    model_A_ref = ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

And then just do in your admin.py

```
class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_filter=('model_A_ref',)

admin.site.register(ModelB, ModelBAdmin)
```

Comment: I understand your approach but i think it doesnt solve what im trying to do. I want to keep the relations the way it is and just pass a parameter to the other ModelForm

Comment: Can you post your modelform?.